# How to count multiple array is empty or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my view Controller, I'm using UITableView, in that every custom cell I'm loading data from different array, now if particular cell does not have data then showing `NO-Data` but now if every cell doesn't have data then I want hide UITableView and show `No-Data` image. Can some-one help me out.

Right now I thought counting multiple array's & checking whether it is empty or not. But I think it would not be feasible solution.

Anyone having better solution for this???

Comment: Please show `numberOfSections:` & `numberOfRowsInSection:`

Comment: `tableView` itself have  `.backgroundview` property you can set no data image there at.

Comment: but how should i identify whether my all cells are empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
if self.ary.count == 0 && self.ary1.count == 0 //multiple arrays
{
  self.tableview.setBackgroundText(stringValue: "No Data")
}

 extension UITableView {
     func setBackgroundText(stringValue:String) {
        let backgroundLabel = UILabel()
        backgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        backgroundLabel.textAlignment = .center
        backgroundLabel.text = stringValue
        backgroundLabel.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        backgroundLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.backgroundView = backgroundLabel
        self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    func removeBackgroundText() {
        self.backgroundView = nil
    }
}
```